# How to set a checkbox to be checked using a link or button

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm creating a quote builder and rather than having small and fiddly checkboxes I'd like to create some nice big 'SELECT' buttons that can check the checkbox behind the scenes.

I'd also like to add a class to the containing div when the checkbox is checked so I can change the styling using CSS.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3 grey_box">
    <h2>Title to go here...</h2>
    <a href="" class="select_link button">Select</a>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="add-on[]" value="{add_ons:title}" checked="" />
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using a label instead. This will allow you click the text to toggle the checked state, without having to write any code around it.

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3 grey_box">
  <h2>Title to go here...</h2>
  <label>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="add-on[]" value="{add_ons:title}" checked="" />
    Select
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks phaze0, using the label as a clickable item is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give the checkbox a ID or class to identify it but below shows how you can check it when it's been changed.

```
$('checkbox').change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $(this).parents('div:first()').addClass("ron-burgandy");
       }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    $(".select_link").click(function() {
            if($(".checkbox").prop("checked") == true){
                 $(".checkbox").prop("checked", false);
            else {
                 $(".checkbox").prop("checked", true);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do something like this:

```js
$('#btnSelect').click(function () {
    $('#checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    $('#containingDiv').css("background", "green");
});
```

```css
#containingDiv {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col span_1_of_3 grey_box">
     <h2>Title to go here...</h2>

    <button id="btnSelect" class="select_link button">Select</button>
    <input id="checkbox" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="add-on[]" />
</div>
<div id="containingDiv">Content goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a button as your "checkbox" and make a jquery function to check your actual checkbox while making the actual checkbox hidden.

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3 grey_box">
    <h2>Title to go here...</h2>
    <button>Select</button>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="add-on[]" value="{add_ons:title}" checked="" />
</div>


button:visited {
  background: green;
}
input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

$('button').click(function(){
  $('button').css('background','green');
  $('input').attr('checked');
  if ($('.checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    //do whatever when checked
  }
});
```